# Dynamic Spinner - drop down list can not be click - Android

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I include a dynamic spinner at a page. 
When click the spinner, it will drop down the selection with image and text.
The problem is when I want select one of the value below like "Category B", it can not be click.
Why? Any problem at my code?

Really need help from someone.

Thanks

*Category.java***

```
private Spinner iconSpinner;
String[] iconArrays = {"Category A", "Category B"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorydetails);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

    iconSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.iconSpinner);
    iconSpinner.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.icon_row, iconArrays));
    iconSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}



public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) CategoryDetailsActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_row, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.iconLabel);
        label.setText(iconArrays[position]);

        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (iconArrays[position]=="Category A"){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_catA);
        }
        else{
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_catB);
        }

        return row;
    }
}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), 
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

***icon_row.xml*****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stringIcon"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/iconLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icon_row.xml

Remove the **android:textIsSelectable="true"** from **TextView**

Answer (score 1):

```
iconSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Did u try this??

**EDIT**

Try this method,

**In activity_main.XML**

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:entries="@array/list"
            android:prompt="@string/select_menu" />
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="select_menu">Select Category</string>

    <string-array name="list">
        <item >Category A</item>
        <item >Category B</item>

    </string-array>
```

**Java file**

```
iconspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cat_list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    cat_list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    iconspinner.setAdapter(cat_list);

    iconspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    iconspinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

I have tried this and it is working fine. just check it

Comment: Yes, it still can not be click.

Comment: <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/iconSpinner" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:prompt="@string/icon_prompt"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
       ></Spinner>

Comment: Above is the XML I had add the spinner

Comment: String selecetedtext = iconSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),    "selected text "+ selecetedtext,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
add this line in onItemSelected method.

Comment: Yes, I know this work. I just want add some icon in the spinner item. So I use dynamic to build the spinner item, but the result is the item can not be click.